# Python equivalent of Fortran list-directed input

Tags: python, format, fortran, ascii

I'd like to be able to read data from an input file in Python, similar to the way that Fortran handles a list-directed read (i.e. `read (file, *) char_var, float_var, int_var`).

The tricky part is that the way Fortran handles a read statement like this is very "forgiving" as far as the input format is concerned. For example, using the previous statement, this:

```
"some string" 10.0, 5
```

would be read the same as:

```
"some string",      10.0
5
```

and this:

```
"other string", 15.0 /
```

is read the same as:

```
"other string"
15
/
```

with the value of `int_var` retaining the same value as before the read statement. And trickier still this:

```
"nother string", , 7
```

will assign the values to `char_var` and `int_var` but `float_var` retains the same value as before the read statement.

Is there an elegant way to implement this?

Comment: Are the quotes mandatory for strings (i.e. - are they always there? )

Comment: It is not called free format, but *list-directed* I/O http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap02/read-1.html

Comment: jsbueno, no, the quotes are only required if there is a space or "," in the string, to prevent it being treated as multiple fields.

Comment: Vladimir F, thanks for the clarification. Couldn't think of the term.

Comment: Reading your reply to Vladimir F as acquiescence, I've updated the terminology in the question.  I've also removed what could be considered an off-topic request for external resources.  If you're not happy with either of those, please roll that edit back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was not able to find a solution to this problem, I decided to write my own solution.

The main drivers are a reader class, and a tokenizer. The reader gets one line at a time from the file, passes it to the tokenizer, and assigns to the variables it is given, getting the next line as necessary.

```
class FortranAsciiReader(file):

def read(self, *args):
    """
    Read from file into the given objects
    """
    num_args = len(args)
    num_read = 0
    encountered_slash = False
    # If line contained '/' or read into all varialbes, we're done
    while num_read < num_args and not encountered_slash:
        line = self.readline()
        if not line:
            raise Exception()
        values = tokenize(line)
        # Assign elements one-by-one into args, skipping empty fields and stopping at a '/'
        for val in values:
            if val == '/':
                encountered_slash = True
                break
            elif val == '':
                num_read += 1
            else:
                args[num_read].assign(val)
                num_read += 1
                if num_read == num_args:
                    break
```

The tokenizer splits the line into tokens in accordance with the way that Fortran performs list directed reads, where ',' and white space are separators, tokens may be "repeated" via `4*token`, and a / terminates input.

My implementation of the tokenizer is a bit long to reproduce here, and I also included classes to transparently provide the functionality of the basic Fortran intrinsic types (i.e. Real, Character, Integer, etc.). The whole project can be found on my github account, currently at https://github.com/bprichar/PyLiDiRe. Thanks jsbueno for inspiration for the tokenizer.

Answer (score 3):

That is indeed tricky - I found it easier to write a pure-python stated-based tokenizer than think on a regular expression to parse each line (tough it is possible).

I've used the [link provided by Vladimir](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap02/read-1.html) as the spec - the tokenizer have some doctests that pass.

```
def tokenize(line, separator=',', whitespace="\t\n\x20", quote='"'):
    """
    >>> tokenize('"some string" 10.0, 5')
    ['some string', '10.0', '5']

    >>> tokenize(' "other string", 15.0 /')
    ['other string', '15.0', '/']

    >>> tokenize('"nother string", , 7')
    ['nother string', '', '7']

    """
    inside_str = False
    token_started = False
    token = ""
    tokens = []
    separated = False
    just_added = False
    for char in line:
        if char in quote:
            if not inside_str:
                inside_str = True

            else:
                inside_str = False
                tokens.append(token)
                token = ""
                just_added = True
            continue
        if char in (whitespace + separator) and not inside_str:
            if token:
                tokens.append(token)
                token = ""
                just_added = True
            elif char in separator:
                if not just_added:
                    tokens.append("")
                just_added = False
            continue
        token += char
    if token:
        tokens.append(token)
    return tokens


class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, length=None):
        self.length = length
    def __call__(self, text):
        if self.length is None:
            return text
        if len(text) > self.length:
            return text[:self.length]
        return "{{:{}}}".format(self.length).format(text)


def make_types(types, default_value):
    return types, [default_value] * len[types]


def fortran_reader(file, types, default_char="/", default_value=None, **kw):
    types, results = make_types(types, default_value)
    tokens = []
    while True:
        tokens = []
        while len(tokens) < len(results):
            try:
                line = next(file)
            except StopIteration:
                raise StopIteration
            tokens += tokenize(line, **kw)
        for i, (type_, token) in enumerate(zip(types, tokens)):
            if not token or token in default_char:
                continue
            results[i] = type_(token)
        changed_types = yield(results)
        if changed_types:
            types, results = make_types(changed_types)
```

I have not teste this thoughtfully - but for the tokenizer -
it is designed to work in a Python `for`statement if the same fields are repeated over and over again - or it can be used with Python's iterators `send` method to change the values to be read on each iteration.

Please test, and e-mail me (address at  my profile) some testing file. If there is indeed nothing similar, maybe this deserves some polishing and be published in Pypi.

Comment: The behaviour of list-directed input is a _lot_ more complicated than that link makes out.

Comment: Is this one complete enough? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnc5/index.html

Comment: A recent Fortran standard (drafts as linked in the tag wiki) will provide as much detail as you could want. It could be worth noting that if the hope is to provide an emulation of list-directed input rather than act like the statement of the question, one may have to be concerned about defined input procedures.

Comment: That's an interesting design. I was leaning towards a function that took as arguments, the file, and a list of variables to assign into. The tokenizer is decent start, but as you can see from the oracle page you linked to, it needs some more work to be a full emulation. I can probably implement one myself, it's just if I ever get around to it.

Comment: As you should know before trying to code in Python, you can't "pass variables" to a function and have their values modified in the calling context - like one does with passing a variable address (pointer) in C.

There are several  cleaner alternatives (in respect of less colateral effects the function can cause on the calling environment)- the function could return a dictionary, or it could return a tuple you assign to your variables (this is the option I choose above)

Comment: I was thinking you would probably need to implement classes for character, integer, and floating point types so it would more closely resemble Fortran's strict types, and at that point you CAN modify objects. The problem with returning a tuple of the values is, the function won't know how many return values it's looking for, and empty fields will end up modifying variables, which is not what happens in Fortran.

Comment: Sorry @Brad - if you look the code above the function _does_ know how many return values it needs - the "types" tuple gives the type for each of them, And Python int, float, types can already work as constructors for the types  -  the character class is there because the reduced specification in that cs.mtu.edu link describes one can specify the string width - that is padded or truncated. This class does that. 

Moreover, empty fields keep the values of the previous reads with the same types - the code above was written with that purpose in mind.

Comment: TL;DR: if this is not clear enough - if people confirm there is no other way of doing this, I intend to evolve this solution obey the full Fortran specs and relase it on pypi - please let me know.

Comment: @jsbueno that was unclear to me without an example, but I see it now. It just seemed like a slightly less clean interface, but maybe not. In Fortran, character variables must be declared with a given length (with an exception in the latest standard), so the padding/truncating becomes inherent. I had started putting together the 'structure' of a Fortran Ascii File Reader [here](https://github.com/bprichar/PyLiDiRe), but if you've got the time and desire, I'd be happy to let you take the lead on implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107264/discussion-between-brad-richardson-and-jsbueno).